# javascript not loading image error::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, file-not-found

Hey guys i am building dice roller website using random in javascript but after setting attributes for dice image i am getting file not found error.Images are stored like images/dice.png

[image]

[image: ack.imgur.com/TBRUD.png]

Comment: try `./images/..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your actualy seting the image's source to the str `randomImg` rather then the variable's value what you want to do is remove the `""` that make it a string and use the variable
so the last line of the js would look like `document.querySelectorAll[0].setAttribute('src',randomImg)`